Sentry Fingerprint grouping - Ignore Subdomain
I have a site with multiple subdomains (ex. test1.website.com/test/123, test2.website.com/test/456, test3.website.com/test/789, etc) that is surfacing JS errors via Sentry (ex. error = illegal invocation). Each of these is surfaced with a separate finger print in Sentry but ideally they would all fall into the same bucket via *.website.com. In reviewing finger print values these come through as
[
  Illegal invocation,
  https://test1.website.com/test/<ID>
]

and
[
  Illegal invocation,
  https://test2.website.com/test/<ID>
]

Ideally these would be instead grouped as...
[
  Illegal invocation,
  https://*.website.com/test/<ID>
] 

Is this possible via Sentry settings or does this need to be handled programmatically - any thoughts?
